# Receive iPhone User Data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sql, ios, database

I am creating an app with various tests and I need a way to receive the test results from the users. Is there a way for me to save the test results when the user is done taking the test and be able to access the results from my computer or something? Thanks in advance,
       Joshua

Comment: are you are talking about creating web services for your app that it would use to upload data? I think you are going to have to be more specific.

Comment: I guess. I'm not exactly sure how I would do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are familiar with sql commands.Why dont you try sqlite for creating a database where you can store the results, update them ,retrieve them.you can refer to this site http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IPhone_Database_Implementation_using_SQLite 
or this one
http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/08/19/iphone-programming-tutorial-creating-a-todo-list-using-sqlite-part-1/

Answer (score 3):

In an app I am making I used JSON, JavaScript Object Notation, to communicate between my app and a web server, where I store my info.  It is fairly simple to use.  Check out this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/2965/how-to-write-an-ios-app-that-uses-a-web-service.  This is what I used and I am fairly new to programming in general, and I just had to make a few adjustments to make it work.  This is pretty broad, but this should get you in the right direction.